# calling begin and end on vector returned by member function

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator

I have this class:

```
class foo{
public:
    const std::vector<int> get_v() const{
         return v_;
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> v_
};
```

Can I use it like this?

```
int main(){
    foo f;
    some_non_inplace_std_function(f.get_v().cbegin(),f.get_v().cend());
}
```

Will the first `f.get_v()` point to the same vector of the second `f.get_v()` ?

Comment: No, `get_v` each time creates a temporary vector and copies the `foo::v_` into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you making a new copy each time you are calling `get_v`. To solve this you could return a const reference:

```
 const std::vector<int>& get_v() const { return v_; }
```

Answer (score 6):

`get_v()` returns by value, so each time you call it you get a new copy of the original. That means that the begin and end iterators obtained from different calls to `get_v()` do not belong to the same sequence.

If you really intend to return by value, then you need to copy the result in order to use the iterator pair:

```
auto v = f.get_v();
some_non_inplace_std_function(v.cbegin(), v.cend());
```

Otherwise, you can return by reference, or return iterators or an iterator range object directly from `foo`.

```
const std::vector<int>& get_v() const{ ... }
```

or

```
struct foo{
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator begin() const{ return v_.begin(); }
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator end() const{ return v_.end(); }
 ....
private:
    std::vector<int> v_
};
```

Answer (score 4):

```
const std::vector<int> get_v() const{
     return v_;
}
```

You are returning a copy of the vector `v_`. You may want to return reference to the `v_`

```
const std::vector<int>& get_v() const{
     return v_;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should change to return reference like

```
const std::vector<int>& get_v() const {
     return v_;
}
```